# module.exports function behaves differently than regular function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

I have a function:

```
test = function() { 
         console.log("hello");
         return "goodbye"; 
       }
```

When I call it, it behaves as expected:

```
   -> test()   
      hello   
   <- "goodbye"
```

However if I try to to put this function in a separate file called "tester.js":

```
module.exports = {
  test: function() { 
      console.log("hello");
      return "goodbye"; 
  }
};
```

...it does not behave the same way. The `console.log` statement is not output:

```
var tester = require('./tester');
-> tester.test()
<- "goodbye"
```

Even though if I type `tester.test` and `test` at the console they look identical.

Why is this and how can I fix it? Note this is a toy example; in my actual code, I am returning an object where I modified `object.stdout.on('data', function() {...})` to log to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an old "bug" in nwjs wherein required modules receive a different the node version of `console` rather than the WebKit version.

The bug is described here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/196

A workaround suggested by @karlrwjohnson is to pass `console` as an argument to your module functions.